# Why are default arguments in constructor ignored?

Tags: python, default-value

Tested on Python version 3.7.5

Consider the small running example

```py
from collections import deque


class Tree:
    def __init__(self, ident=None, childs=[]):
        self.ident = ident
        self.childs = childs
        print(f'childs of {ident}: {childs}')

    def traverse_bfs_path(self):
        queue = deque([([], self)])
        while len(queue) > 0:
            path, node = queue.popleft()
            yield path, node
            queue += [(path+[i], n) for i, n in enumerate(node.childs)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Tree('a')   # Works as expected
    depth = 1
    spread = 1

    for path, node in tree.traverse_bfs_path():
        if len(path) < depth:
            nc = len(node.childs)
            for _ in range(nc, spread):
                node.childs.append(Tree('-', [])) # without the second argument this will not run!
```

This prints to console:

> childs of a: []
>   childs of -: []
>   childs of -: []

I am wondering - when you remove second argument in the last line `[]` Python does not the default value (`[]` as well) but seems to use the same array for `childs` as the previous instance of Tree.

Removing the second argument results in an infinity loop and prints the following to the console:

> childs of a: []
>   childs of -: []
>   childs of -: [<**main**.Tree object at 0x7efbfe329590>]

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Mutable default arguments are a common gotcha - see https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments.

Comment: Read the dupe. Use `def __init__(self, ident=None, childs=None): if not childs: childs = []` as workaround

Answer (score 1):

You have a list as the default value for `childs`, so you're experiencing the side effects of mutable default args.

Essentially, whats happening is Python evaluates the param the first time the function/method runs, and uses that for the subsequent runs

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments